# How to read floating values?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am very very new to machine learning. I try to understand using TensorFlow.
I have data like:

```
[['0', '-0.500', ' 1.600', ' 0.280', ' -8.326', ' 6.827', ' 1.540', ' 0.998', ' 4', ' 1.404', ' 0.83', ' 3.58'], ['1', ' 1.260', ' 0.210', ' -7.562', ' 7.880', ' 1.880', ' -0.573', ' 9', ' 0.887', ' 4.80', ' 1.30', '']]
```

For binary values, I used `x_train = np.uint8 ([[int(j) for j in e] for e in data1])`.
What comment should I use for floating values? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the forum :)

Python has the following built-in types: `bool`, `int`, `float`; you can cast a variable into one of them by simply calling their associated constructor.

```
float('0.5') # Returns the floating-point number 0.5
bool(0) # Returns the boolean False
int(1.2) # Returns the integer 1
```

Unless you know what you are doing, numpy deprecates the use of np.int and `np.float`, and you should prefer in most cases Python's built-in types `int` and `float`.

To convert an array to an array of integers in numpy, simply write

```
np.array(data1, dtype=int)
```

Now, since your data appears to be heterogenous, you might be interested in libraries like [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html), which offers some kind of "powered-up" numpy arrays with `pandas.DataFrame` because they can hold values of several data types.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['0', '-0.500', ' 1.600', ' 0.280', ' -8.326', ' 6.827', ' 1.540', ' 0.998', ' 4', ' 1.404', ' 0.83', ' 3.58'], ['1', ' 1.260', ' 0.210', ' -7.562', ' 7.880', ' 1.880', ' -0.573', ' 9', ' 0.887', ' 4.80', ' 1.30', '']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This will initialize a DataFrame with columns of type string since this is what is in your list of values. You can then convert individually each column to the desired type.

```
df[0] = df[0].astype(int) # Converts the values in the first column to integers
df[1] = df[1].astype(float) # Converts the values in the second column to floating-point numbers.
```

You can check this by printing `df.dtypes`.

```
0       int64
1     float64
2      object
3      object
4      object
5      object
6      object
7      object
8      object
9      object
10     object
11     object
dtype: object
```